# How to SSH Tunnel with -L command?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

Im trying to use a SSH tunnel for games, website browsing etc.
I'm trying

```
ssh -L 8080:runescape.com:80 ****@*****.serveftp.com
```

Problem is, when I reach `localhost:8080`, it says "Service unavailable".

I also tried http://whatismyip.com and http://iplocation.net, with almost same result. I'm curious how it works (with `-D` parameter, I managed to change ip to my home server's IP).

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or if `-L` tunnelling sites etc. is simply not allowed.

Comment: Try pinging one of those sites, then navigating to the IP (no tunnel). If that doesn't work, then you know your problem isn't SSH (assuming your firewall allows the access).

Comment: Also make sure that outbound 80 is open on *.serveftp.com (might not be), and that your remote user is allowed to bind ports over SSH (may be restricted). Check these things, update your question, and we'll help you from there :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would check if:

1. are u root on remote machine ?
2. have u tried to resolve the hostname runescape.com ?
3. There are some firewall problem ? your 8080 port is open ? and the 80 of runescape is open (I mean from the servftp, or u have to open outgoing port 80?) ?
4. the remote port 22 is open ?

Comment: root wouldn't be needed if he is binding to a high port (like 8080). Local firewall should not be running against localhost. If he can successfully connect, port 22 is definitely open. #3 is not a bad idea.